# CSS left and rghtDiv not aligning to left and right but top and bottom

Tags: html, css, jsp, stylesheet

My css and html look like below. `mRow` is the main div and within that is my `mRowLeft` and `mRowRight`.

However instead of left and right I see them appear top left and bottom right.

```
div.mRow {
  padding: 2px 25px 2px 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  width: 350px;
  /*border:1px solid green;*/ 
}


.mRowLeft {
  padding: 2px 25px 2px 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  float: left;
  text-align:left;
  width: 48%;
  /*border:1px solid green;*/ 
}

.mRowRight {
  padding: 2px 25px 2px 0;
  margin-top: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  float: right;
  text-align:left;
  width: 48%;
  /*border:1px solid green;*/ 
}
///....
<div class="mRow">
  <div class="mRowLeft"></div> --label
  <div class="mRowLeft"></div> --10rows
  <div class="mRowRight"></div> --label
  <div class="mRowRight"></div> --10rows
</div>
...//
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be putting your label and content under the same left/right div.

```
<div class="mRow">
  <div class="mRowLeft">
    <div>--label</div>
    <div>10rows</div>
  </div> 

  <div class="mRowRight">   
    <div>label</div>
    <div>10rows</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you can either use inline-blocks:

```
.mRow {
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 350px;
}

.mRowLeft,
.mRowRight {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
  width: 50%;
}
```

or use flexbox:

```
.mRow {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 350px;
}

.mRowLeft,
.mRowRight {
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.mRow
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="mRow">
<div class="mRowLeft">
  dfsf
  <div class="mRowLeft">sdfvs</div> 
</div>

<div class="mRowRight">
  sdfs
  <div class="mRowRight">sdfsd</div>
</div> 

</div>
```